# How could I call forRoot method in loadChildren () => XPTOModule?

Tags: angular

I have a Module Feature in NPM. I can load this module this way:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MyContentModule } from 'my-contentModule'

const routes: Routes = [
 { 
      path: 'my-path', 
      loadChildren: ()=> MyContentModule
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The code above works. But I need pass a data configuration to my module in forRoot Method.

I try this unsuccessfully:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { 
      path: 'my-path', 
      loadChildren: ()=> MyContentModule.forRoot({})
    }
];
```

What are the alternatives to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stay registered, I can pass a data this way:

```
MyContentModule.forRoot({}).ngModule
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I have some services in the providers array insdie forRoot. it throw error of these services not provided in console .

Comment: Which version are you using? What is your scenario? Do you have any example?

Comment: This is great answer. Solves `No NgModule metadata found for forRoot`

Comment: this is a great answer to me as well.

Comment: this will use original module without providers added by static method

Answer (score 1):

If you have some service that needs to be injected,

check the following website and codes.
This is worked for me.

```
// other imports are removed for brevity
import { NgModuleFactory } from "@angular/core";
import { ChildModuleFactory } from "./child-module-factory";

@NgModule(/* module metadata is removed for brevity */)
export class FooModule {
  static withOptions(foo = "foo"): ModuleWithProviders<FooModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: FooModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: FOO,
          useValue: foo
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  static asChild(...params: FooOptions): NgModuleFactory<FooModule> {
    return new ChildModuleFactory(FooModule.withOptions(...params));
  }
}
```

[How to Configure Angular Modules Loaded by the Router](https://volosoft.com/blog/how-to-configure-angular-modules-loaded-by-the-router)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but thought I would post for others traveling here with the questions.  I too had providers supplied in my `forRoot` method, so the approved answer didn't work for me.  What did work for me was wrapping it into a "bundle" module.  Example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyContentModule } from './my-content.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [MyContentModule.forRoot({})]
})
export class MyContentBundleModule {}
```

and then load the bundle instead like usual:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { 
      path: 'my-path', 
      loadChildren: () => MyContentBundleModule
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

since angular 14 you can add providers to the route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'my-path', 
    loadChildren: ()=> MyContentModule,
    providers: [{ provide: Foo; useValue: 'bar' }]
  }
];
```